# Restricted shell rush "invalid uid" error

Tags: scp, restricted-shell

I am setting up a new local account on a Debian buster server. The account name is "auto-upload". The entry in `/etc/passwd` looks like this:

```
auto-upload:x:1060:1060:auto-upload:/home/auto-upload:/usr/sbin/rush
```

As you can see I am attempting to use the ["rush" restricted shell](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/software/rush/) (version 1.8) with this account. The rush configuration file is

```
debug 1

rule default
  acct on
  limits t10r20
  umask 002
  env - USER LOGNAME HOME PATH
  fall-through

rule scp-to-debrepo
  command ^scp (-v )?-t( --)? /srv/repos/?
  set[0] /usr/bin/scp
  match[$] ! /\.\.
  transform[$] s,^/incoming/,,
  chroot /srv/repos
  chdir /srv/repos
```

When I attempt to `scp` a file to that account I see this in the server logs:

```
2021-12-03T12:20:25.240111-08:00 myserver rush[22679]: debug level set to 1
2021-12-03T12:20:25.240755-08:00 myserver rush[22679]: Serving request "scp -t /srv/repos/basic/incoming" for auto-upload by rule default
2021-12-03T12:20:25.240971-08:00 myserver rush[22679]: Serving request "scp -t /srv/repos/basic/incoming" for auto-upload by rule scp-to-debrepo
2021-12-03T12:20:25.254718-08:00 myserver rush[22679]: invalid uid 1060
2021-12-03T12:20:30.257645-08:00 myserver sshd[22678]: Received disconnect from 192.168.225.188 port 45518:11: disconnected by user
```

Why is it telling me "invalid uid 1060" and how do I fix this?

Comment: Does `1060` have an entry in `/etc/shadow`? Is `1060` unique in `/etc/{passwd,shadow}`? What does `/etc/nsswitch.conf` say?

Comment: Hello muru, did you manage to get rid of this error? I'm facing exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 1):

I didn't managed out how exactly `invalid uid` error linked to the real issue reason, but for sure identified that it caused by `chroot` option misconfiguration - config example provided on man page *(and mentioned in your question)* wouldn't work by default

As per said on [rush man page for `chroot` config option](https://www.gnu.org.ua/software/rush/manual/rush.html#index-chroot) - we'll need to have binaries under chroot directory, other way user simply wouldn't have access to them

Config param `chroot /srv/repos` means that `/srv/repos` directory will be treated as `/`, so you will need to have scp binary under `/srv/repos/usr/bin/scp` path or it wouldn't work and will throw `invalid uid` error

> rule: **chroot** *dir*
>
> Change the root directory to that specified in dir. **This directory
> will be used for file names beginning with ‘/’. ...**
>
> The directory dir must be properly set up to execute the commands. For
> example, the following rule defines execution of sftp-server in an
> environment chrooted to the user’s home directory:
>
> ```
> rule sftp
>   match $program ~ "^.*/sftp-server"
>   set [0] = "bin/sftp-server"
>   chroot "~"
> ```
>
> For this to work, **each user’s home must contain the directory bin
> with a copy of sftp-server in it**, as well as all directories and
> files that are needed for executing it, in particular lib.

Comment: @virgiled maybe my answer will help you too :)